# Flash player disappears when developer console open

Tags: flash, google-chrome

I am embedding a swf with swfObject. If I set the `wmode` param to "direct", "window", or "gpu", the swf will disappear anytime I open the chrome developer console. This does not occur with the other wmodes (transparent and opaque). I would really like for the "direct" mode to work for the hardware acceleration, but I need the console open for debugging.

Comment: I also have this issue did you find a work around?

Comment: nope. just using opaque until I'm done debugging.

Comment: Same with Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

Disable your flash plugin (Comes with Chrome) from **chrome://plugins/**
Download a Debug version of Flash from: **https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html** and try.

Comment: Fails. Have you tested this yourself or was this just a guess?